# Would the following question be considered on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Would the following question be considered on topic here:

**Are there any known references of other historically known hidden (secret or otherwise not freely disclosed) passages or rooms within the Vatican?**

[Vatican hidden (secret) rooms and passages?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34849/vatican-hidden-secret-rooms-and-passages)

I asked this question some time ago on History SE, but I am rather disappointed in the results.

Would it be permitted to post it here in hopes of better results.

Comment: Doesn't our ability to read about these passages on a public internet forum sort of undermine the notion that they are "secret?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think probably not, it doesn't really seem to concern the religious side of the Vatican. And it has been very highly upvoted on History.SE. Maybe consider posting a bounty to see if anyone else can give another answer?

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is exactly why I posted it here first.